# Bounded linear operators on Hilbert space is a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $B(H\to H)$ is the algebra of boulded linear operators on this space, with adjoint map $T\mapsto T^*$ and the operator norm, I want to show that $B(H\to H)$ is a unital C$^*$ algebra. I can prove that $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$, but how to show the $C^*$ identity, that is $\|T^*T\|=\|T\|\|T^*\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$ \Vert T^*T \Vert = \sup \{\langle T^*T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1 \} =\\= \sup \{\langle T v,Tw\rangle | \: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1  \} = \Vert T \Vert^2$$
As you already know $\Vert T\Vert = \Vert T^*\Vert$, so we have $\Vert T^*T \Vert = \Vert T^*\Vert \Vert T\Vert$.

**Remark**: I used that, for any $T\in B(H\to H)$,

$$\Vert T \Vert = \sup \{\langle T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1 \}$$

This is easy to prove. Here are the details:

If $\Vert T \Vert=0$, then $T=0$ and so we have $\Vert T \Vert=0=\sup \{\langle T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1 \}$.

Suppose $\Vert T \Vert\neq 0$. Note that 
$$\Vert T\Vert = \sup\{\Vert Tv\Vert \:|\: \Vert v \Vert=1\} = \sup\{\Vert Tv\Vert \:|\: \Vert v \Vert=1 \textrm { and } \Vert Tv\Vert \neq 0 \}= \\ =\sup\left \{\left \langle  Tv, \frac{Tv}{\Vert Tv\Vert} \right \rangle \:|\: \Vert v \Vert=1 \textrm { and } \Vert Tv\Vert \neq 0 \right\} \leq \\ \leq \sup \{\langle T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1 \} \leq \Vert T\Vert$$
So we have
$$\Vert T \Vert = \sup \{\langle T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1 \}$$

Comment: You use the equality $\|T\|=\sup\{\langle Tv,w\rangle:\|v\|=1,\|w\|=1\}$, how to prove this?

Comment: I updated the answer to use the equality $\Vert T \Vert = \sup \{\langle T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert \leq 1, \Vert w\Vert \leq 1 \}$ and included a proof of this inequality.   The proof of the equality $\Vert T \Vert = \sup \{\langle T v,w\rangle |\: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1 \}$ is a little bit longer because we would have to normalize $w_\epsilon$.  So I chose the equality with a shorter proof. The reasoning in the answer remains the same.

Comment: I think you proof can be simplified. Note that $\|T\|=\sup\{\|Tv\|:\|v\|=1\}=\sup\{\langle Tv,Tv/\|Tv\|\rangle:\|v\|=1\}\leq \sup\{\langle Tv,w\rangle:\|v\|=1,\|w\|=1\}$ since $Tv/\|Tv\|$ is a vector with norm $1$, (we may treat $Tx=0$ separately).

Comment: @XiangYu Nice. You are right.  I edit the answer to reflect your suggestion. I included the details.

Comment: @Ramiro I don't understand why $$\sup \{\langle T v,Tw\rangle | \: \Vert v\Vert = 1, \Vert w\Vert = 1  \} = \Vert T \Vert^2$$ holds. I've tried like made to justify, and every resource I've come across always skips this step.

Comment: @user193319 first to all $\langle Tv, Tw\rangle\leq\lVert T\rVert^2$, the opposite inequality follows from $v=w$.